# Ubuntu installatiion on external usb hard disk doesn't load

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, external-hard-drive, bootloader, ubuntu-14.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 on a usb external hard disk using this youtube video tutorial: [Tutorial: Install Ubuntu 13.04 To An External Hard Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDM2LqFoHv4)

I have windows 10 installed on the common hard disk of my laptop.

According to the tutorial, I set the following partitions for the free space of my usb external hard disk:

- `/boot` partition: 500 MB Size
- `Swap space`: 4000 MB Size;
- `/` partition": (rest of disk space) about 100,000 MB.

I then selected the boot partition and installed Ubuntu on it according to the tutorial.

*I have already modified the bios settings to allow the usb external hard disk to load first and before all other media.*

The problem here is that when I restart the computer and have the usb external
hard disk correctly plugged to the computer, ubuntu doesn't load, and instead Windows 10 loads.

Am I missing a configuration setting on Windows 10 to allow the usb external hard disk to load instead of Windows 10?

Or am I missing something or doing anything wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the internet a lot, I could successfully boot from my usb external hard drive (I am not using a pendrive or flash stick, that way installation would have been easier). I found that there were bios boot settings on my computer which needed to be changed in order for my laptop to boot from the usb external hard drive.

The bios settings I changed were two items:

1. **Secure Boot**- I set it to "Disabled": Microsoft Secure Boot is a component of Microsoft's Windows 8 operating system that relies on the UEFI specification’s secure boot functionality to help prevent malicious software applications and "unauthorized" operating systems from loading during the system start-up process.
   While there is some concern that Microsoft Secure Boot will make it difficult to install Linux or other operating systems on a Windows 8 computer, the secure boot functionality in Windows 8 is primarily designed to protect users from rootkits and other low-level malware attacks by blocking unauthorized (non-signed) executables and drivers from being loaded during the boot process.
2. **Legacy Support**- I set it to "Enabled": When legacy support is enabled, BIOS will load "Compatibility Support Module" to support Legacy OS such as Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP and DOS. When Legacy Support is disabled, BIOS will boot in UEFI mode without CSM to support newer OS such as Windows 8.

After changing these settings, while restarting my laptop, after the hp logo screen appeared, I noticed that below the screen a label was showing for some seconds, saying "press ESC for advanced boot options". On the right timing I pressed "ESC" and a boot menu appeared, showing the different media from which I could boot, and there appeared my USB external hard disk labeled with the Ubuntu version I installed. Finally I chose my USB external hard disk from the boot menu and pressed enter and Ubuntu finally loaded successfully.

Comment: Windows 7 x64 supports UEFI.  If you want to use a 64-bit version of Windows 7 there is absolutely no reason to run in Legacy mode.  The most recent versions of Ubuntu actually support Secure Boot, so unless you are running an OS that does not support it, Secure Boot does not need to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

1. Windows 8 and later versions use a *hybrid boot* process, bypassing startup. You must do a complete shutdown to force a full bootup cycle. One way is to enter the following from the [command line or *Run* dialog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx):

> shutdown -s -t 00

2. Be sure your USB ISO is UEFI compliant.
3. Depending on the UEFI/BIOS, you may need to enable booting from the USB port: that is often turned off by default for secuirty.
4. You might do better following the [Ubuntu directions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu). Following those, I've run directly from a USB stick and then used the same device to install the OS. BTW, there is no need to partition the USB stick unless you wish to optimize it for long-term use as a boot device.

Comment: I am not using an usb pendrive nor a usb flash stick, I am using an usb external hard drive or hard disk.

Comment: Ah! The comments above should apply to an external HDD as well as flash drive. BTW, it might be easier to write the ISO to a flash drive of 2 GB or larger, plug in both the USB HDD and flash drive, and boot from the flash drive. Then install Ubuntu on the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread but I'm having the same issue. I had some old SATA III HDD's laying around collecting dust so I decided to use them for storage but recently I've decided to use one for Ubuntu. I'm pretty sure UEFI is hardware based security and these old disks don't have them so I'm going to try and disable the UEFI. But be careful when doing this. I once lost a nice PC due to being locked out of BIOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).